# Nothing displays when I refresh the page sometimes

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I Created a WebPart which draws a Dashboard using canvas.js,but sometimes when I refresh the page,nothing displays.This only happens in IE.
When I debug it,it points to these codes:

```
var ctxBg = document.getElementById(backgroundId).getContext("2d");
```

It says " Object doesn't support property or method 'getContext' ".
How can I handle it?

Comment: Hard to tell with the info you provided. Can you paste in more of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it only happens "sometimes", that could indicate that your code is executing before your canvas element has loaded.  I won't get into IE support for canvas, or working with SharePoint's nuances, but it seems like a good place to start is making sure that your entire page has loaded before executing your canvas method.

Comment: I replaced the old code with "window.onload=function(){my function that draws the dashboard}",though it works,sometimes I can still feel the short time that nothing displays before it really shows.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that older versions of IE does not support the canvas element.

For Canvas to work in IE9 you need trigger standards mode by setting a valid doctype and remember to include <canvas>.